# PHP Pagination displaying page number twice

Tags: php, pagination

I am creating a project with pagination in it. I wrote some code and it's working but in some point its displaying unwanted data and other than that, it is working fine. I can't figure it out what is the problem in my code. Could you guys please check what is missing?

I have 12 rows in my table and I am displaying 5 data in each page. which is going to give me the total number of page = 3. That is fine, but the problem is, when I am at the first page then the page number 3 is displaying twice and when in the other page then it's displaying completely fine.

Look at the paging numbers...
[image: Image 1]
you can see, page number 3 is displaying twice! But when I am going to page 2 or 3 Then it's working fine.

Here is my code

```
$items_per_page = 5;

if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $current_page = $_GET["page"];
} else {
    $current_page = 1;
}

$items_to_skip = ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page;

$pageQuery = "SELECT COUNT(ta.id) as total FROM ambulance ta";
$pageResult = $db->select($pageQuery);

if (!$pageResult) {
    $total_items = 1;
} else {
    foreach($pageResult as $rowCount){ 
        $total_items = $rowCount['total']; 
    }
}

$max_page = ceil($total_items/$items_per_page);

echo "<nav><ul>";

$previous = $current_page - 1;

if ($current_page != 1) {
    echo "<li><a href='mypage?page=".$previous."'><i class='fa fa-backward'></i></a></li>";
}

$page_span = 2; 

$middle_min = max($current_page - $page_span, 1); 
$middle_max = min($current_page + $page_span, $max_page); 
$pages      = range($middle_min, $middle_max); 

if ($middle_min !== 1) { 
    array_unshift($pages, 1); 
} 
if ($middle_max !== $max_page) { 
    $pages[] = $max_page; 
} 

$output = ''; 
$previous_page = 0; 
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    if ($page - $previous_page > 2) { 
        $output .= "..."; 
    } else if ($page == $current_page) { 
        $output .= "<li class='active'><a href='mypage?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>"; 
    } else {
        $output .= "<li><a href='mypage?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>";
    }
    $previous_page = $page; 
} 

echo $output;

$next = $current_page + 1;

if ($current_page != $max_page) {
    echo "<li><a href='mypage?page=$next'><i class='fa fa-forward'></i></a></li>";
}

echo "</ul></nav>";
```

Now my question is, how am I going to display page number 3 once when I am in first page?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: when I am displaying 3 item per page then its happening in the 2nd page..
Look...
[image: Image 2]
Page 4 is showing twice!

Comment: Are you using Laravel ? Because they have a package to do this harassing task (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination)

Comment: @FrédéricKlee No, its raw php.

Comment: I found here (http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) a basic pagination exemple, myabe could help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! :)
And it is working completely fine...

```
$items_per_page = 5;

if (!$result) {
    $total_items = 1;
} else {
    $total_items = COUNT($result);
}

$max_page = ceil($total_items/$items_per_page);

echo "<nav class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center'>";
    
$previous = $current_page - 1;
    
if ($current_page != 1) {
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='en/blog?page=$previous'><i class='fa fa-backward' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>";
}
    
$page_span = 2; 

$middle_min = max($current_page - $page_span, 1); 
$middle_max = min($current_page + $page_span, $max_page); 
$pages      = range($middle_min, $middle_max);
    
if ($middle_min !== 1) { 
    array_unshift($pages, 1); 
}
    
$output = ''; 
$previous_page = 0; 
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    if ($page - $previous_page > 2) { 
        $output .= "..."; 
    } else if ($page == $current_page) { 
        $output .= "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='en/blog?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>"; 
    } else {
        $output .= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='en/blog?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>";
    }
    $previous_page = $page; 
}
if ($current_page != $max_page) { 
    $output .= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='en/blog?page=".$page."'>Last Page</a></li>";
}
    
echo $output;
    
$next = $current_page + 1;
    
if ($current_page != $max_page) {
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='en/blog?page=$next'><i class='fa fa-forward' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>";
}

echo "</ul></nav>";
```

The results:
[image: result]